# Passing in params to \N{name} unicode string

Tags: python

My question is; Do we in python have a workaround for passing in named params into an escaped unicode segment? for example

```
print u"No... haha {name} is a \N{MALE SIGN}".format(name = 'lisa', gender = 'MALE')
```

to

```
print u"No... haha {name} is a \N{{gender} SIGN}".format(name = 'lisa', gender = 'MALE')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do this way, since `\N{name}` substitutions are done during parsing (before `.format()`, that is executed at runtime).

You can use [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html) to get unicode character by name. Like this:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> print u"No... haha {name} is a {gender}".format(name = 'lisa', gender = unicodedata.lookup('MALE' + ' SIGN'))
No... haha lisa is a ♂
```